# calling a function only when a key is pressed not when it is released

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, keyboard-events

As the snippet below runs , each time a key is tapped,the function *LowLevelKeyboardProc* is called. But the problem is it is called both at the time of pressing a key and at the time of releasing a key.It means , per one tap the function is called two times.But I want the function be called only one when the key is pressed and not when the key is released.

Even if I can filter the pressing and releasing of keys inside the function *LowLevelKeyboardProc*,it will be fine. Is there any way I can do this.

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  // call the function only if the key is pressed,else ( i.e key released) do nothing
}

BOOL WINAPI installHook(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fwdReason, LPVOID lpvReserved){
  handleKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, hinstDLL, 0);
  MSG msg;

  while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  return msg.wParam;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fwdReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) { // ENTRY POINT
 if(hookThreadHandle==NULL) { 
    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress = &installHook;
    hookThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, lpStartAddress, NULL, 0, &hookThreadId);
 }
 return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the way LowLevelKeyboardProc is called, but inside the function you can know the reason of the call:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
     if ( nCode < 0 )
     {
         return CallNextHookEx(handleKeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
     }

     if ( wParam == WM_KEYDOWN )  // possibly you want also WM_SYSKEYDOWN
     {
         // do what you need
     }
}
```

Comment: My winapi is a bit rusty, but I believe that CallNextHookEx should also be called in the case where he doesn't handle the message.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley - yes, but programmer may want to hide some keyboard messages, in this case CallNextHookEx is not called.

Comment: From MSDN: If nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must pass the message to the CallNextHookEx function without further processing and should return the value returned by CallNextHookEx. So, if nCode < 0, just return CallNextHookEx - this is obligatory.

Comment: Usually CallNextHookEx is called also when nCode >= 0, but this is your decision. For example, if you want to hide some keyboard messages, don't call CallNextHookEx and just return TRUE.

Comment: @AlexFarber what do you mean by hide some keyboard messages ?

Comment: If CallNextHookEx is not called, keyboard message handling stops. This means, any window in the system will not see this keyboard message in its window procedure. Some applications use this to stop some unwanted Windows functionality, like Alt+Tab, Windows key etc.

Comment: Unexpected is happening as I used the above conditions ! On pressing some of the keys different windows open up,when I am writing on notepad it looses focus. If i try to print `*` firefox opens up !

Comment: can we please discuss this here @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18002/discussion-between-y-e-p-and-alex-farber